# Expand a div on click and shrink anothers and return to normal after clicking again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a site I made, I have 5 divs in a container with the width of 20%. What I want to do is a function that helps me with a simple thing: when I click one of the divs I want that div to become wider like 40% and the other divs from the container to get smaller, like 15% and when I click back again on the same div to get back to normal and keep the transition when I go from a div to another.

I have an exemple but I am at start with the JS and I don`t get it to much from there.
What I want is a simple function to do the same thing.

Here is the example: https://wellingborough.fluencycms.co.uk/

Comment: please add code you have use

Comment: @gerdi I tried something like this: $('#quick > div.quicklink').click(function(){
 $(this).animate ({width:"40%"},"slow").siblings().animate({'width': '15%'}, "slow");
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little update regarding kdureidy anwser:
- it doesn't "toggle" the state if you click again
- it doesn't take the number of "boxes" into account

Here is an improved version:

```
$('body').on('click', '.box', function(e) {
  var $target = $(this)
    , targetIsActive = $target.hasClass('active')
    , $boxes = $('.box')
    , boxesCount = $boxes.length
    , inactiveWidth = 100 / boxesCount
    , activeWidth = inactiveWidth * 2
    , othersActiveWith = (100 - activeWidth) / (boxesCount - 1)
    ;
  if(!targetIsActive) {
      $boxes.removeClass('active').css('width', othersActiveWith + '%');
      $target.addClass('active').css('width', activeWidth + '%');
  } else {
      $boxes.removeClass('active').css('width', inactiveWidth + '%');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xw1e34yy/

Answer (score 0):

Like this: 
You need to give all divs same class to be able to reset there width, and using javascript target the clicked div to change the width, also use transition to make it animated smoothly.

```
$(".box").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".box").css("width", "15%");

  $(e.currentTarget).css("width", "40%");
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5s3urL96/

Comment: Thanks! Looks cool, but when I click back again on a box I want that all divs to get back to the normal width of 20%.

Comment: it is very simple, use new class named expanded, and check on it